# how do i install cisco packet tracer 5.3.3 on ubuntu 14.04 LTS - 64 bits?

Tags: software-installation

How can I install packet tracer on ubuntu 14.04 64bit?

I installed it but when I try to open a file that I made with it in ubuntu 14.04 64bit, packet tracer tell me that `this file is not compatible with this version of packet tracer`

Answer (score 0):

I can only tell : packet tracer not work on ubuntu 14.04 lts.
this get from the search.
I risolved with software virtualbox

Answer (score 0):

I have Packet Tracer 6.0.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit and I can open saved files without any problem, try to use Packet Tracer v6.0.1